# How to limit the Question list in a quiz?

Tags: android, arrays, database, sqlite

I am having a problem with the Quiz part of my Application. I need a 100 question per category, but I just need to display 20 question to be answer by the user.  That 100 question used to randomize the questions to have different questions to display. How do i limit the question?

Comment: Okay I'm sorry, this is my first time to ask a question.Peace

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `int`. Every time you open a random question you set your `int` + 1. And if your `int` is 20, you stop opening a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but:

1. Let's assume you have a Java/Android "Quiz" app, and you want to randomly select and display 20 questions from a list of 100.
2. Let's also assume that your 100 questions are stored in a Java "List<>".
3. Finally, let's assume you have a "Question" class that contains both the question and the corresponding answer.

Then one possible solution might be:

```
    // Fetch 20 random questions
    List<Question> selectedQuestions = new ArrayList<Question>();
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i=0; i < 20; i++) {
       int idx = random.nextInt(questionsList.size());
       selectedQuestions.add( questionsList.get(idx));
    }
    // Display these questions
    return selectedQuestions;
```

Comment: Ohhh. Thank you! I'm going to try it. :)